In C# setting a List<Type> to a List<IType> where Type implements IType
Why doesn't this line List<IFruit> l = apples; work? and how do I make it work?
public interface IFruit {
    void Blend();
}


public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public void Blend()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apple blending");
    }
}

public class Fruit : IFruit
{
    public void Blend()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fruit blending");
    }
}
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        apple.Blend();
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.Blend();
        List<Apple> apples = new();
        List<IFruit> l = apples;
    }
}


If this was valid: List<IFruit> l = new List<Apple>() then what would this do?  l.Add(new Banana());  It's not a type error because a Banana is presumably an IFruit, but it's also not valid because Banana isn't an Apple.

"and how do I make it work" - You don't, see the duplicate.

You are missing an I!
    public class Apple : IFruit
    {
        public void Blend()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Apple blending");
        }
    }

    public class Fruit : IFruit
    {
        public void Blend()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fruit blending");
        }
    }
    class Program 
    {
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
            Apple apple = new Apple();
            apple.Blend();
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
            fruit.Blend();
            List<Apple> apples = new();
            List<IFruit> l = apples;
      }
    }


No, that still will not work.
